# Trying to get TensorFlow working in Jupiter notebook on Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, macos-high-sierra

Having started without `python3` installed (only the default `python2`) on High Sierra, I was following the PluralSight course ["Building and deploying keras models in a multi-cloud environment"](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=keras-models-building-deploying-multi-cloud-environment&author=janani-ravi&name=8936f423-38e1-4bd6-ad08-ae26a3b534e5&clip=4&mode=live) and found that I could not run the following command in `jupiter notebook`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Here are the versions I have currently installed:

```
brew --version
Homebrew 1.7.6
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 1f874; last commit 2018-09-29)

python -V
Python 2.7.15

python3 -V
Python 3.6.6

jupyter --version
4.4.0

pip -V
pip 18.0 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I had originally installed `python3` via the download from their webpage, but decided to revert to version `3.6.0` (though it insists on displaying `3.6.6`) via `brew` after reading on SO that the current version of tensorflow is only compatible with python `3.6.0`.

When I open jupyter notebook, create a new notebook and enter the command `import tensorflow as tf` and hit `run` the terminal shows this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'
[W 22:16:31.449 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 22:16:31.450 NotebookApp] Kernel e25f532c-ce0f-4ac3-bc3c-4b54864d0994 died, removing from map.
[W 22:17:16.442 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from e25f532c-ce0f-4ac3-bc3c-4b54864d0994
[E 22:17:16.447 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: e25f532c-ce0f-4ac3-bc3c-4b54864d0994)
^C[I 22:17:50.731 NotebookApp] interrupted
```

Should I try to uninstall everything I've installed and start from scratch or am I doing something very basically wrong which is easy to correct?

I get the same error whether I run in a python environment or not.

Comment: The same under Ubuntu Linux. Though not too much earlier I worked on the 3.6 environment, now I'v got the same error message and phenomenon. My (I guess temporary) solution was, that I've downgraded Python 3.5 and uninstall/reinstall ipython and jupyter though not sure is needed both.

Comment: How do you downgrade python? Which versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using now conda and simply: conda install python=3.5. But if you're using any other env manager, there is similar solution too. Currently with this downgrade I've got 3.5.6.

Comment: Anyway I'm sure. that there is some combination of versions and dependencies to use python 3.6, but as I'm using a payed cloud server, after a few hour test I decided not to give more money to provider... And it's working now.